# Add to cart not working on ipage hosting server

Tags: php, security, server, hosting, web-hosting

I have hosted one website in iPage.com server.

In this server add to cart was not working. When we clicked on it the first time, the product was added to the cart, but after we added a second product, the cart page was empty.

I have searched a lot but can't find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

In the above issue I found the solution after googling a lot so please be careful about this small issue.

Please check your `php.ini` file setting (you can edit this in your control panel; ipage does not allow you to upload files that are in the root directory).

Change this line:

```
register_globals == off
```

By default this is `ON`.

Answer (score 0):

Visit Ipage **controlpanel**

Click on **CGI and Scripted Language Support**

Now **PHP Scripting**

Search for **register_globals**

Make this:
**auto_globals_jit = Off**

It's Done!!!

Your cart will be filled with the products!